# How can I ensure the final price of a product can't fall below its minimum price after applying a promotion in Shopware6?

Tags: shopware6

I am trying to implement a solution based on the minimum price of a product. For example, I have product X in my shopping cart, where its price is $100 and the minimum price is, say, $90. On top of that there is a promotion for 20% of the total cart. And now the final price of product X cannot fall below its miminal price. That is, despite the 20% discount, ultimately it can only be 10% in this case.

There is an example in the documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/6.4/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/change-price-of-item

Only I don't quite understand, because it seems to me that there you can control the prices of products. In the `process` method, the `$toCalculate` variable always has only lines with type `PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE`. At least as far as I can see.

I've tried something like this:

```
public function process(CartDataCollection $data, Cart $original, Cart $toCalculate, SalesChannelContext $context, CartBehavior $behavior): void
{
    $promotions = $toCalculate->getLineItems()->filterType(LineItem::PROMOTION_LINE_ITEM_TYPE);
    $lineItemsCollection = new LineItemCollection();
        
    foreach ($promotions as $promotion) {
        $definition = new PercentagePriceDefinition(
            1
        );

        $promotion->setPriceDefinition($definition);

        $lineItemsCollection->add($promotion);
    }
        
    $this->promotionCalculator->calculate($lineItemsCollection, $original, $toCalculate, $context, $behavior);
}
```

But it gives me an error:

`Line item with identifier "cb7925eb127140a5872fd7bf8b9435aa" is not stackable and the quantity cannot be changed.`

I also found the `DiscountCalculatorInterface` interface, but I don't quite know how to use it. Can you direct me somehow?